# LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder cause decode() did not read anything but decoded a message

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I use LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder parse my package, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129415/decode-did-not-read-anything-but-decoded-a-message), LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder should't cause `decode() did not read anything but decoded a message.`

but when my application run for a period of time, it will appear.

my client will send six length byte heartbeat message in every 5 seconds, and send about one hundred length byte message every 10 seconds.

those message all complete, there is no loss.

there is my code :

```java
public class RecvDecoder extends LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder {
    private static final int MAX_FRAME_LENGTH = 10240;
    private static final int LENGTH_FIELD_LENGTH = 4;
    private static final int LENGTH_FIELD_OFFSET = 0;
    private static final int LENGTH_ADJUSTMENT = 0;
    private static final int INITIAL_BYTES_TO_STRIP = 0;


    public RecvDecoder() {
        super(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN,
                MAX_FRAME_LENGTH,
                LENGTH_FIELD_OFFSET,
                LENGTH_FIELD_LENGTH,
                LENGTH_ADJUSTMENT,
                INITIAL_BYTES_TO_STRIP,
                true);
    }

    @Override
    protected byte[] decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf byteBuf = (ByteBuf) super.decode(ctx, in);

        if (byteBuf == null) {
            return new byte[0];
        }

        int length = byteBuf.readIntLE();

        byte[] data = new byte[length];

        byteBuf.readBytes(data, 0, length);

        byteBuf.release();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand how the problem happened.

all beacuse

```java
        if (byteBuf == null) {
            return new byte[0];
        }
```

when message not growth to the specified length, if you return none null but empty byte array, some happen in netty, it will check last receive length and readable bytes length, if its equal, and you return empty byte array, netty don't understand why message length is not enough but you trigger decoding behavior.

so change it:

```java
        if (byteBuf == null) {
            return null;
        }
```